# Deserilizing the json to list of an object throwing error. Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"})

Tags: c#, json, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to deserialize the Json to List object of Student which conister of studentName and studentId.  I do get the jsonResponse with around 200 students but when I get to deserialize I got the below error. I did reserch for this error and the fix for the issue is similar to the code that I have so I am not sure what is wrong.

Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[MyApp.Models.Student]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.

```
public static async Task<List<Student>> GetUserInfo()
{
    var token = await AccessToken.GetGraphAccessToken();
    // Construct the query
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, Globals.MicrosoftGraphUsersApi);
    request.Headers.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);

    // Ensure a successful response
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request);
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

    // Populate the data store with the first page of groups
    string jsonResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    var students = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Student>>(jsonResponse);

    return students;   
}
```

Below is the JSON response from Microsoft Graph Api

```
{
  "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users(studentName,studentId)",
  "value": [
    {"studentName":"Radha,NoMore","studentId":"420"},
    {"studentName":"Victoria, TooMuch","studentId":"302"}
  ]
}
```

C# student Class:

```
public class Student
{
    public string studentName { get; set; } 
    public string studentId { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Please add a [mcve] and tag this with the language you're using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JSON response contains a **`value:`** property, and that property contains the students as array data. Therefore you'll need to make an additional class that has a `List<Student> value` property, deserialize to that class, and then you can use the List of Students that is in the `value` property, as follows:

```
var listHolder = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<StudentListHolder>(jsonResponse);
var list = listHolder.value;
foreach (var student in list)
{
    Console.WriteLine(student.studentId + " -> " + student.studentName);
}
```

This is the additional class:

```
public class StudentListHolder // pick any name that makes sense to you
{
    public List<Student> value { get; set; }
}
```

Working demo (.NET Fiddle): *https://dotnetfiddle.net/Lit6Er*

Comment: Peter thanks for your help,it did resolve my issue. I did try something  as you mention but never thought that I have to change the List<Student> property name to value in StudentListHolder class